# How do I use the C preprocessor to make a substitution with an environment variable

Tags: c++, environment-variables, c-preprocessor, substitution

In the code below, I would like the value of `THE_VERSION_STRING` to be taken from the value of the environment variable `MY_VERSION` at compile time

```
namespace myPluginStrings {
const  char* pluginVendor = "me";
const  char* pluginRequires =  THE_VERSION_STRING;
};
```

So that if I type:

```
export MY_VERSION="2010.4"
```

`pluginRequires` will be set at "2010.4", even if `MY_VERSION` is set to something else at run time.

**UPDATE:** (feb 21) Thanks for your help everyone. It works.
As I'm using Rake as a build system, each of my CFLAGS is a ruby variable. Also the values need to end up in quotes. Therefore the gcc command line for me needs to look like this:

```
gcc file.c -o file -D"PLUGIN_VERSION=\"6.5\""
```

Which means this is in my Rakefile:

```
"-D\"PLUGIN_VERSION=\\\"#{ENV['MY_VERSION']}\\\"\""
```

Comment: This is not something the preprocessor will do. This is something your build system would have to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can use the command line parameter [`-D`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) with gcc to `#define` a value at compile time.

i.e.:

```
$ gcc file.c -o file -D"THE_VERSION_STRING=${THE_VERSION_STRING}"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-DTHE_VERSION_STRING="$(THE_VERSION_STRING)"`?

Comment: @bk1e Yeah, I think you're right -- the docs actually show it as `-D name=definition` though, so maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: @bk1e: not parenthesis - braces would work but are not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, the space wasn't the point of my comment, the quotes were. `sh` eats double quotes unless you escape them with backslashes, and `make` preserves double quotes. `export FOO="bar"` is valid for both `make` and `sh` derivatives, so it's unclear whether the environment variable's value contains double quotes. If it doesn't, then you need to add double quotes when you use `-D`, and adding them before the macro name won't work--you need a C string literal to the right of the `=` sign. Also, `make` uses parens and `sh` uses braces.

Comment: And hey, I just noticed the `$` indicating that you were assuming `sh` not `make`. Also, I forgot that `make` invokes commands in rules via a subshell, so you still need to use backslashes with `make`.

Answer (score 1):

> In the code below, I would like the value of THE_VERSION_STRING to be taken from the value of the environment variable MY_VERSION at compile time

No, you can't do it like this. The only way to extract environment variables is at runtime with the `getenv()` function. You will need to explicitly extract the value and copy it to `pluginRequires`.

If you want the effect of a compile-time constant, then you'll have to specify the definition on the compiler commandline as [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299824/how-do-i-use-c-preprocessor-to-make-a-substitution-with-an-environment-variable/2299847#2299847) suggests.