# Does the preprocessor pass environment variables?

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor

Does the preprocessor have a mechanism to access environment variables directly as defines, without the need to define them on the command line?

For instance,

```
SOME_VAR=foo gcc code.c
```

and

```
#if ENV_SOME_VAR == "foo"
#define SOME_VAR_IS_FOO
#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I use c preprocessor to make a substitution with an environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299824/how-do-i-use-c-preprocessor-to-make-a-substitution-with-an-environment-variable)

Comment: No, the standard C preprocessor has no such mechanism, and I'm not aware of any compiler extensions that provide such a feature either.  However, build systems do this all the time, including Cmake and GNU Autotools.  A simple shell script would do this as well, though all of these mean you'd need to test the environment variable to determine whether to define `ENV_SOME_VAR`, in which case, why not just define it using something like `-DENV_SOME_VAR="${SOME_VAR:-unfoo}"`, which would define `ENV_SOME_VAR` in your C file as the value of `$SOME_VAR` if it's set or "unfoo" if it's empty or unset.

Comment: @ThomWiggers no, similar, but not the same.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the standard C preprocessor has no such mechanism, and I'm not aware of any compiler extensions that provide such a feature either.

However, you can do this using a build system, such as Cmake or GNU Autoconf, the latter being a part of the GNU Autotools build system. A simple shell script would do this as well, though all of these options mean you'd need to test the environment variable to determine whether to define `ENV_SOME_VAR`, in which case, you might just define it using something like the following:

```
-DENV_SOME_VAR="${SOME_VAR:-unfoo}"
```

That would define `ENV_SOME_VAR` in your C file as the value of `$SOME_VAR` if it's set or to the string "unfoo" if `$SOME_VAR` is empty (null) or unset.